# Как присоединить таблицу "ключ-значение", чтобы ключи стали столбцами?

Tags: oracle, plsql

В БД `Oracle 11g` имеется 2 таблицы:

### Items

```
ITEM_ID | NAME
=================
1       | first
2       | second
```

и

### ItemFields

```
ITEM_ID | FIELD_NAME | VALUE 
=====================================================
1       | Field1     |  aaa     
1       | Field2     |  bbb 
2       | Field1     |  ccc     
2       | Field2     |  ddd
```

Каждой строке из Items соответствует несколько строк из ItemFields.

Как получить таблицу вида

```
ITEM_ID | NAME   | Field1 | Field2
===================================
1       | first  | aaa    | bbb
2       | second | ccc    | ddd
```

Я вижу несколько вариантов, но хотелось бы выбрать наиболее эффективный:
1)  Использовать `LEFT JOIN` и перебирать данные в клиентском приложении
2)  Использовать `LEFT JOIN` и пройтись циклом по результату в хранимой процедуре, сформировав новый резалтсет
3)  Использовать подзапросы

```
 SELECT i.ITEM_ID, i.NAME, 
 (SELECT VALUE FROM ItemFields 
   WHERE ITEM_ID=i.ITEM_ID AND FIELD_NAME='Field1') as Field1, 
 (SELECT VALUE FROM ItemFields 
   WHERE ITEM_ID=i.ITEM_ID AND FIELD_NAME='Field2') as Field2 
 FROM Items
```

4)  Использовать `PIVOT` (честно говоря не совсем понял как с ним работать и умеет ли он работать с несколькими полями: VALUE_INT, VALUE_DATE)

Comment: Предположу что FIELD_NAME в ItemFields будут добавляться и заранее не известны?

Comment: @AkaInq FIELD_NAME заранее известны. Более того, в моей хранимой процедуре будет использован конкретный список FIELD_NAME, а не все.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Предложу еще один способ:

```
SELECT i.ITEM_ID, i.NAME,
       max(decode(f.FIELD_NAME,'Field1',f.VALUE,NULL)) f1,
       max(decode(f.FIELD_NAME,'Field2',f.VALUE,NULL)) f2,
       max(decode(f.FIELD_NAME,'Field3',f.VALUE,NULL)) f3,
       max(decode(f.FIELD_NAME,'Field4',f.VALUE,NULL)) f4
  FROM Items i
  LEFT JOIN ItemFields f ON f.ITEM_ID=i.ITEM_ID
 GROUP BY i.ITEM_ID, i.NAME
```

А что касается `pivot` - вы можете выбрать одно из значений из разных колонок с помощью того же `decode`, но результирующее значение все равно должно быть только одно, получается не так гибко как в первом варианте. А выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT i.ITEM_ID, i.NAME, f.FIELD_NAME, f.VALUE_INT, f.VALUE_DATE
     FROM Items i
     LEFT JOIN ItemFields f ON f.ITEM_ID=i.ITEM_ID
)
PIVOT (
 max(decode(FIELD_NAME,'Field1',VALUE_DATE,'Field3',VALUE_DATE,VALUE_INT))
 for FIELD_NAME in('Field1','Field2','Field3','Field4')
)
```

Каков будет результирующий тип данных у колонок сказать сложно, проверял на таблице с числовым и символьным полем, с виду типы сохранились, хотя возможно он привел все сам к строке.

Comment: насколько Ваш вариант более эффективен, чем вариант с подзапросами?

Comment: @GreenBee А как вы предлагаете это оценить, в каких единицах. Сравните планы выполнения одного и другого варианта, посмотрите стоимость. Подзапросы в списке выборки обычно зло ибо плохо поддаются оптимизации, заново выполняются на каждую строку ну и просто несколько обращений к таблице ради одной строки. с другой стороны, group by конечно медленнее, чем прямое чтение только одной таблицы и тут вопрос скорее в общем объеме данных. И обычно group by эффективнее, чем перебор курсором в цикле и самостоятельное накопление тех же данных (хоть в процедуре, и тем более на клиенте)