# SQL вывод столбцов из строк

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть таблица, телефонный справочник:

```
FIO                    |type |Ph      |
Иванов Семен Павлович  |Внутр|11-11-11|
Иванов Семен Павлович  |Внешн|3056    |
Сидоров Петр Евгеньевич|Внутр|22-22-22|
Сидоров Петр Евгеньевич|Внешн|4067    |
```

Как вывести такую таблицу SQL запросом?

```
FIO                    |PH1     |PH2
Иванов Семен Павлович  |11-11-11|3056
Сидоров Петр Евгеньевич|22-22-22|4067
```

Comment: Какая СУБД? А то data pivoting очень разный в разных диалектах.

Comment: база данных oracle

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как присоединить таблицу "ключ-значение", чтобы ключи стали столбцами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532242/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: См. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2066378 , *Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT: Examples*

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT t1.FIO as FIO, t1.Ph as PH1, t2.Ph as PH2
FROM (
    SELECT FIO, Ph 
    FROM <table> 
    WHERE type = 'Внутр'
) AS t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT FIO, Ph 
    FROM <table> 
    WHERE type = 'Внешн'
) AS t2
ON t1.FIO = t2.FIO;
```

Comment: А если у человека не будет одного из номеров? Тут нужен `full outer join`

Comment: @Андрей, верно. Заменил.

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
select a.fio,
       (select b.ph from table b where a.fio = b.fio and b.type = 'Внутр'),
       (select b.ph from table b where a.fio = b.fio and b.type = 'Внешн')
from   table a
group by a.fio
```

Answer (score 1):

В MySQL можно так

```
select FIO,
       GROUP_CONCAT(case when type='Внутр' then Ph else '' end) PH1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(case when type='Внешн' then Ph else '' end) PH2
  from ...
 group by FIO
```

в Oracle должно что то быть похожее, [тут например](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

Answer (score 1):

Так никто и не написал про PIVOT, комментарии не в счет

```
with s (fio, typ, ph)
  as (select 'Иванов Семен Павлович'
           , 'Внутр'
           , '11-11-11'
      from dual
      union all
      select 'Иванов Семен Павлович'
           , 'Внеш'
           , '3056'
      from dual
      union all
      select 'Сидоров Петр Евгеньевич'
           , 'Внутр'
           , '22-22-22'
      from dual
      union all
      select 'Сидоров Петр Евгеньевич'
           , 'Внеш'
           , '4067'
      from dual
      )
   , rez
  as (select *
      from (select s.fio
                 , s.typ as k
                 , s.ph as val
            from s
            )
      pivot (min(val) for k in ('Внутр','Внеш'))
      )
select * from rez
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select FIO
,max(case when type = 'Внутр' then Ph else NULL end) Ph1
,max(case when type = 'Внешн' then Ph else NULL end) Ph2
from t1
group by FIO
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё поиграться с UNION ALL

```
SELECT 'НАЗВАНИЕ ПЕРВОЙ СТРОЧКИ' AS "НАЗВАНИЕ ПЕРВОГО ПОЛЯ",
   'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ 1' as "НАЗВАНИЕ ВТОРОГО ПОЛЯ"
FROM ТАБЛИЦА
UNION ALL
SELECT 'НАЗВАНИЕ ВТОРОЙ СТРОЧКИ', 'ЗНАЧЕНИЕ 2'
FROM ТАБЛИЦА
WHERE условие для удаления декартового произведение
```